# Rewrite query string parameter into URL Apache

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, query-string

URL coming into Apache:

```
localhost:8888/game?level=0
```

URL that should be coming out of apache:

```
localhost:8888/level0/game
```

Could someone kindly help me to create this rewrite ?

Tried to solve it with following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^game\/+(.*?)\?+level=+([0-9]+) /level$2/$1 [L,QSA]
```

With no luck since it does not match.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: You would get more help if you provide what you have attempted to solve this.

Comment: @hwnd Added the solution I have tried

Comment: Are you sure you want that direction of rewriting (making something static look dynamic?) most often rewrite rules are written the other way around. Anyway, in RewriteRule you will be able to match just the url path (with no query string). You need `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .....` to capture query string values, see https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: @guido yep, this is the correct direction. So, adding RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} game still does not fix it.. Could you kindly seuggest firther direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to capture values from the query string, you need a `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` directive, so that captured group will be available as `%n` placeholders in the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^level=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^game /level%1/game [L]
```

If you type `/game?level=0` in the browser, apache will open `/level0/game`; no need to append the query string to the rewritten url (`QSA` flag)

Comment: This does not seem to work, when I copy paste these settings and open start url I am getting Not Found

The requested URL /game was not found on this server. Works with ^game

Comment: @Peter what is the start url?

Comment: and does a `/level0/game` file exist under the document root for that context?

Comment: @Peter ah sorry, I missed the last _Works with ^game_ part of your first comment, I had a typo

Comment: @anubhava actually it will rewrite and not redirect

Comment: Ah just realized you don't have `R` flag, but then I thought OP wanted to have `localhost:8888/level0/game` URL externally (but I may be wrong)

Comment: @anubhava yep he got unusual requirement, as you can see I made sure asking in a comment below the question

Comment: Yes read your comment, that was really unusual to have URLs other way round :)

Comment: Polishing it further I have added '?' at the end of the RewriteRule to prevent parameter being send to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(game)\?(level)=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2%3/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^(level)(\d+)/([^/.]+)/?$ $3?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```