# Redirect link with parameters using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect this link:

/content/catagorie.php?item=Notariaat

To this link:

http://www.meddo.nl/vacatures/notariaat/

I used this:

```
Redirect /content/catagorie.php?item=Notariaat http://www.meddo.nl/vacatures/notariaat/
```

But it didn't work.

Thx

Comment: Try searching google for `php create SEO friendly url`, there are thousands of guides to do this.

Comment: Do you want to do it in .htaccess or inside the `catagorie.php` file itself ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rewrite SEO friendly url's like stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168364/how-to-rewrite-seo-friendly-urls-like-stackoverflow)

Comment: To capture values from the query string, you need to use `RewriteCond`. Possible duplicate of [Rewrite query string parameter into URL Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721423/rewrite-query-string-parameter-into-url-apache)

Answer (score 0):

use  this 301 redirect

```
 Redirect 301 http://example.com/content/catagorie.php?item=Notariaat http://www.meddo.nl/vacatures/notariaat/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these 2 rules in root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /content/catagorie\.php\?item=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /vacatures/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^vacatures/([^/.]+)/?$ /content/catagorie.php\?item=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: What is the full URL you entered in browser and also show your full .htaccess in question.

Comment: RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /content/catagorie\.php\?item=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /vacatures/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^vacatures/([^/.]+)/?$ /content/catagorie.php\?item=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

Redirect 301 /content/catagorie.php?item=Notariaat http://www.meddo.nl/vacatures/notariaat/

Comment: In which directory is this .htaccess located?

Comment: in the root of the wordpress

Comment: If it is WP then where are WP default rules? I don't see them in your rules